# In OS X 10.9 (xcode 5.1), how to show local notification on top-right(menu bar) in my program?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsusernotification

Why local notification is no supported by OS X 10.9? I know IOS has UILocalNotification Class.

I want to show some notification bellow menu bar which is generated by my program.

Is there any alternate way to do this? Or should I write my own local notification view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [NSUserNotification functionality](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which goes along with the MacOS [NSUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012260).

I've linked the documentation at Apple to help you out.

As you are learning, many classes and objects supplied in the iOS SDK don't have exact same classes and objects in the MacOS SDK.  Anything with "`UI`" in the framework name is usually meant only for iOS.

Comment: Another small question, why my program user notification icon in OS X notification center is mac default icon. I use another 'image.icns' as my program icon file.

Comment: I delete ~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter/*.db and restart my computer, it is still mac default icon for my program.

Comment: this is a different question and if you ask it in a separate question, I'll try to answer it very quickly...

Comment: OK, i create a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822195/why-my-program-icon-in-os-x-notification-center-is-mac-default-icon